# How to arrange line after line the sequential numbers in text

Tags: notepad++

I am having numbers in text of size 819200 sequentially, like :

2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,......................2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,10,11,11.

When copied this data to some header file in C program they transform to weired symbols(corrupted data) due to the single line numbers arrangement.
Is there any way I can arrange the numbers in line by line as below:
2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,
21,21,22,23,23,24,24,25,26,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,29,29,
.............................................so on new line arrangements.
What I want to do is the numbers should not be in single line, they should be arranged in line by line(each line may contain 100 numbers with comma followed).
Note: I tried word wrap but still the data is in sequential format only.

Comment: This is more of a Notepad question than anything to do with programming in any particular language unless you're intending to create a script to do this.

Comment: I also tried with the run a macro option in notepad++. I want to copy this formatted data to some C program, thats the only intention I mentioned C program.

Comment: If you tried a macro, then it's best to include the macro you've tried. This site is very much about helping those that've made an effort to solve the problem, even if they were unable to put all the pieces together. As a note, these sorts of problems are often pretty easy to solve if you use a scripting language like Ruby or Python for quick little tasks.

Comment: @tadman I am still in search of solution, If any one can provide me some hint on how to solve I can proceed. Please give me any Idea on how to proceed further, I am stuck with this since when copied the system hangs due to large size of data.

Comment: @tadman presently I am manually editing the text which is more painfull.

Comment: It's not clear if this sort of thing should be in your code in the first place. For data like this a simple format is just a binary dump of `int32` type values. If you need it in your code, you'll probably need a simple script. Example in Ruby: `line.split(/,/).map(&:to_i).sort.join(',')`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\d+,){100}`
- Replace with: `$0\n`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

This will add a linebreak after 100 numbers + comma

**Explanation:**

```
(?:      : non capture group
  \d+    : 1 or more digits
  ,      : a comma
){100}   : end group, repeated 100 times
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0      : the whole match
\n      : linefeed
```